# Which Enterprise model is the most technologically advanced?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

This is only the USS ENTERPRISE models. To specify: Their weapons, computer etc.

Comment: Do you have any reason to believe that they sometimes go backwards technologically?  Because that's the only way the answer isn't obviously the [Enterprise-J](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/USS_Enterprise_(NCC-1701-J\)).

Comment: The only other way of looking at this is to ask which ones were most advanced compared with other ships of their time. The NX-01 was the only ship of its kind, while others were broadly similar to other ships, so it would get the prize in that case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The USS Enterprise (NCC-1701-E) captained by Jean-Luc Picard was the most advanced Enterprise built. But if you'd like to include alternate timelines then it'd be the 
USS Enterprise (NCC-1701-J) which is supposedly created around 200 years after the Enterprise E, but is only seen briefly in an episode of Star Trek: Enterprise. Hope this helps! :D